# Is it possible to clone Git repo/branch via Subversion?

Tags: git, svn

I have a Git repository I use for a project. Is it possible to clone and then pull (I don't need to push) to a local machine using Subversion? I just need, from time to time, to get stuff from Git repo but I only have access to Subversion on that particular machine.

Answer (score 0):

#### If the repo is @Github

Example cloning a [ZendSkeletonModule](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule) from a Github repo via Subversion:

`svn co https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonModule/trunk Module`

When you need to pull stuff from the repo just type:

`cd Module && svn up`